# How to get a HTML5 element by XPath by LibXML2 in C++

Tags: c++, libxml2

I want to get `div` HTML tag by XPath by LibXml2 in C++ but it finds nothing while I have many `div` tags in the HTML. When I put something like `/html/body/div[1]/div/div` it even crashes.

```cpp
htmlParserCtxtPtr parse_ctx = htmlCreateMemoryParserCtxt(resp.text.c_str(), resp.text.size());
if (!parse_ctx) {
  std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
  return;
}

xmlXPathContextPtr xml_ctx = xmlXPathNewContext(parse_ctx->myDoc);
if (!xml_ctx) {
  std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
  return;
}

xmlXPathObjectPtr xpath_obj = xmlXPathEvalExpression((xmlChar *)"//div", xml_ctx);
if (!xpath_obj) {
  std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
  return;
}

xmlNodeSetPtr nodes = xpath_obj->nodesetval;
std::cout << nodes->nodeNr << std::endl;   // result is 0.
```

I also tried to use `htmlParseElement` function instead of XML functions, but it shows error on HTML5 tags (unknown tag error).

Answer (score 0):

`htmlCreateMemoryParserCtxt` only creates a parser context and doesn't parse the document yet, so `parse_ctx->myDoc` will be `NULL`. Try `htmlReadMemory` which parses the document and returns an `xmlDocPtr`.